# How do you use the variables from an enum in another class?

Tags: java, printing, enums, constants, enumeration

I'm very new to enums and only have an elementary understanding of programming. I recently found out about enums and believe them to be the perfect solution to some of my problems but need some help on how to incorporate them into my code.

I started by creating an enum class. For now I'm working with 7 constants for my enum, and each constant has 1 String variable describing(?) it. How do i code this? And more importantly how do I access this from another class? For instance I want to print the string relating to the constant that is the current value of my enum. Please help. This was really hard for me to describe so hopefully you guys know what I'm trying to ask for.

Comment: Don't explain your code - put some in your question!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: try this link http://www.java2novice.com/java-lang/enum/defined-inside-class/

Answer (score 2):

This is already covered in the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

```
public enum Animal {
  COW("moo"),  // <== calls constructor with any enum specific data
  HORSE("neigh"),
  SHEEP("ba ba");

  private final String noise; // stores the data

  private Animal(String noise) {  // <== private constuctor
      this.noise = noise;
  }

  public String getNoise() {  // <== allow access to the data
      return noise;
  }
}
```

Access from another class

```
Animal animal = Animal.COW;
System.out.println(animal.getNoise());
```

Comment: `noise` should be `final`.

Comment: But how would you do that without specifying COW? How can I get the corresponding animal sound to print given any given value of the enum?

Comment: Also what function does the private constructor serve here?

Comment: "Note: The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access. It automatically creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself." from official link in my answer...

Comment: You can call getNoise () on any variable of type Animal, just like a normal instance of a given class. I've updated answer to show this

Answer (score -1):

Enum constants override the `toString` method so by default it returns the constant name as a string. You can even override it further.

The Javadocs are your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--.

You can also often use the enum constant itself directly.

```
public enum Rainbow {
  RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, INDIGO, VIOLET;
}
```

Used one way:

```
Rainbow rainbow = findRainbow();
switch (rainbow) {
  case RED:
    rosso();
    break;
  case YELLOW:
    giallo();
    break;
  . . .
  case VIOLET:
    viola();
    break;
}
```

etc.

Also, enums are classes and you can give them more methods, even override a method differently for each enum constant. Like Java already does with `toString`.

@shmosel already gave the link to the enum Tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

To declare an enum, follow this synatx `Colors("RED", "BLUE")`

To access the enum class, declare it as a public class. If the class is in another package, import the class in to the class which is referencing those enums.

Answer (score -3):

sorry my bad for saying to make it static

make it public . so that it can be accessed from any class that the class is imported to .

make somethingn like this from a different class

```
public class DifferentClass
{
    public enum reportType
    {
        firstReport = 1,
        secondReport = 2
    }
}
```

import that class and access it like System.out.println("Report type : " + reportType.firstReport);

Comment: Make what `public static`? Enum constants already are, in effect. Only constants and certain utility methods should be `public static`. Otherwise that pattern causes trouble, generally. Your explanation is unclear what "it" is supposed to be. If you mean a variable to hold an enum value, it's very unlikely that any scope beyond local is needed. Please detail how your suggestion addresses the OP's question.

Comment: I suggest that in this example the enum should be a top-level class, and that its name should adhere to the Java naming conventions. Also, have you tried compiling your code? Because it has errors.